# Latest Message In Conversations - Multiple SQL Statements Combined

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I am working on an inbox application and have a table called Messages that contains all messages sent between users. We are setting this up for a conversational view. If you reply to a message then the message ID of the first message becomes the parentMessageID of all subsequent replies. It has several fields, however for this I am really only concerned about 3 of them. The basic setup with example data is:

```
MessageID (Guid)   |   Date     |  ParentMessageID (Guid)   | recipientID
  00000000           07/11/18         NULL                       1
  11111111           07/12/18         00000000                   2
  22222222           07/10/18         NULL                       2
  33333333           07/11/18         22222222                   1
  44444444           07/01/18         NULL                       2
```

- I know the GUIDs are shortened, it just made it easier to fit on one line.

Right now I have the following:

```
Select * from messages where recipientID = X AND ParentMessageID is null Order by Date DESC
```

These results are turned into a list. After this I loop through the list of messages and check to see if it has any child messages with

```
Select top 1 * from messages where parentMessageID = X order by date desc
```

If this yields a result then I simply replace the parent message in the list with the child message I just found. This works great...but I need to be able to turn this into one SQL query for cache purposes and so that I can use .Skip and .Take for pagination.

I have tried different joins and group by statements with no luck, plus once I figure it out I have to make sure it will work with LINQ. We are using SQL Server 17.

Desired Result set if using above data for reference would be this for recipient ID 2:

```
MessageID (Guid)   |   Date     |  ParentMessageID (Guid)   | recipientID
  11111111           07/12/18         00000000                   2
  44444444           07/01/18         NULL                       2
```

And for recipient 1:

```
MessageID (Guid)   |   Date       |  ParentMessageID (Guid)  | recipientID
  00000000           07/11/18 2:00        NULL                       1
  33333333           07/11/18 1:20        22222222                   1
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the return data you are expecting also do you mean select top 1 * from your 2nd query?

Comment: This smells like a job for a recursive CTE, but I would like to see the desired output, as well.

Comment: Desired output added

Comment: Desired output does neither reflect the data nor the described process.

Comment: If I knew how to make a query to do what I needed to do I wouldn't be asking. I am trying to take a 2 step process and turn it into 1 SQL statement. I do think Brian is right and CTE is the answer, but I am not familiar enough with it.

Comment: Why isn't `MessageId= 22222222` in the desired output?

Comment: @Sirena In your first "desired" output, the first message (11111111) is neither a message with no parent nor is it somewhow related to the other message (44444444).
In your second "desired" output, although the first record is a parent record, the second isn't a child of it. Im not asking whether you know how to write the query but do you understand what you want? Yes, a recursive CTE will be the answer, but to what problem?

Comment: @Sirena Ok, now I think I got what you mean. Nevertheless: Message 11111111 in example 1 (recipient 2) is not a sibling message of a "root message" with recipient 2, and for example 2 (recipient 1): Message 00000000 has exactly one child message (11111111) that did not replace the parent in your desired result, and the other message (33333333) does not have a "root message" with recipient 1. Are you sure to only follow the **latest** thread in a conversation? There could be older threads that are much longer (with a younger "leaf")...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out how to only use the newest child message, I came up with this solution:

```
DECLARE @X int = 2;

WITH
  MsgChildNumbering (MsgID, [Date], ParentMsgID, RcptID, ChildNo) AS (
    SELECT MessageID, [Date], ParentMessageID, RecipientID
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentMessageID ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM Messages 
  ),
  CTE_Msg (MsgID, [Date], ParentMsgID, RcptID, RootMsgID, LevelNo) AS (
    SELECT MsgID, [Date], ParentMsgID, RcptID, MsgID, 1
    FROM MsgChildNumbering WHERE ParentMsgID IS NULL AND RcptID = @X
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.MsgID, c.[Date], c.ParentMsgID, c.RcptID, p.RootMsgID, 1+p.LevelNo
    FROM MsgChildNumbering AS c -- child messages with numbering
      INNER JOIN CTE_Msg AS p -- parent messages from last iteration
        ON c.ParentMsgID = p.MsgID
    WHERE c.ChildNo = 1
  ),
  MsgNumbering (MsgID, [Date], ParentMsgID, RcptID, MsgNo) AS (
    SELECT MsgID, [Date], ParentMsgID, RcptID
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RootMsgID ORDER BY LevelNo DESC)
    FROM CTE_Msg
  )
SELECT MsgID, [Date], ParentMsgID, RcptID
FROM MsgNumbering WHERE MsgNo = 1;
```

- The CTE **MsgChildNumbering** is used to create a numbering of the children so to be able to add only the newest child per parent.
- **CTE_Msg** is the recursive part that starts with all initial messages of a conversation with recipient `@X` and then successively adds the child messages with `ChildNo = 1` (only the newest one per parent).
- Finally, the CTE **MsgNumbering** adds a reverse numbering of the messages in a conversation (same `RootMsgID`) by `LevelNo` to be able to find the latest message per conversation.